# MYSQL insert all values from one table's column to another table based on JOIN / Relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

In this case I have the following table, I need to move all values on user_sessions.session_str to users.user_string based on the user_id. How to achieve this?

```
**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_string varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO users (user_string) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO users (user_string) VALUES (NULL);

CREATE TABLE user_sessions (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id INT,
  session_str varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO user_sessions (user_id, session_str) VALUES (1,1234);
INSERT INTO user_sessions (user_id, session_str) VALUES (2,5678);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
users.*, 
user_sessions.session_str, 
concat('I want ',session_str,' to be copied into users.user_string') as 'help'
FROM users 
JOIN user_sessions on user_sessions.user_id = users.id;
```

| id | user_string | session_str | help |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 1234 | I want 1234 to be copied into users.user_string |
| 2 |  | 5678 | I want 5678 to be copied into users.user_string |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tn8WHKLNckoiwK34JESio5/0)

Answer (score 0):

Then dont insert nulls in the users table. Use `insert into ... select ..` as follows:

```
Insert into users
Select session_str from user_sessions;
```